# How to combine javascript files without plugins?

Tags: javascript, performance, wp-config, configuration

I remember (it seems...) there was a way, maybe some config option, to combine/merge javascript files (for production sites). I mean just with vanilla wordpress code, not plugins.

Am I wrong? If not, how to? Can't find reliable infos.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer separete all my front-end assets from the back-end, so I use `Gulp` to manage (compile, mifify etc..) all my assets.

But if you want to use Wordpress I found this [article](https://code.recuweb.com/2016/how-to-combine-javascript-files-in-wordpress-without-plugin/). I did not test the code, but by just reading and seeing the comment section I think that will work for you.

But I really recommend you to use something Like `Gulp`, `Webpack` or `Yarn` to manage your front-end assets.

Comment: Yes, the linked method is quite involved. I already use codekit, and yes I coud use grunt tools or the like. Not sure this would succefuly work for plugins assets too. I mean, I should reference them all, I guess. It's strange there's nothing automatic right out of the box. Anyway, than you.

Comment: Yep, gulp or similar tools work for plugins too, I just use them in development and when I publish the plugin I just sent the `dist` folder, with the compiled assets for production.

Comment: No i mean 3rd party plugins. I don't think it's easy to reference them all. Also, there could be trouble with updates, no?

Comment: Oh yes, with third party plugin it would be a little pain to try this approach

Comment: So I'll end up with a 3rd party plugin, indeed :P

Comment: Guys did you find any way to accomplish this? I'm struggling with webpack but it's quite a challenge to detect / deregister all wp assets and merge into a unique `dist.js` maintaining all deps.